# how do i select multiple mysql records based on checked checkboxes?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

on page 1 i have a form, then on page 2 which is the processor file, i want to select records based on the checked checkboxes that were checked on page 1.

```
<form action="output.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" id="" class="" name="check_list[]" value="something" />
<input type="checkbox" id="" class="" name="check_list[]" value="something else" />
<input type="checkbox" id="" class="" name="check_list[]" value="yet another thing" />
<input type="checkbox" id="" class="" name="check_list[]" value="one more thing" />
<input type="checkbox" id="" class="" name="check_list[]" value="some name" />
<input type="checkbox" id="" class="" name="check_list[]" value="some other name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

the following foreach can display all the values of everything that was checked, but i don't know how to take it further into my sql select statement to select all the records that have a column field by that name.

```
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) { 
    echo $check . '<br>';  
}
```

lets say in a table called stuff there are these fields

```
id, first_title, second_title
```

so i want to do the following, but obviously this isn't the way to write it.  this is the part i need help with.

```
SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE first_title = $check or second_title = $check
```

lets us further say that these records exist in the table...

```
id    first_title          second_title
-----------------------------------------
1     something            something else
2     yet another thing    one more thing
3     some name            some other name
```

then lets say these checkboxes were checked:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="" class="" name="check_list[]" value="something" />
<input type="checkbox" id="" class="" name="check_list[]" value="one more thing" />
```

so what i want to happen is for my select statement to select record 1 and record 2 and not record 3, because "something" is in the first_title column of the first record, and "one more thing" is in the second_title of the second record, and nothing was checked that is in third record.

i hope i gave as much detail as is needed.  let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: use `||` for `OR` operand in mysql

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen you're excused

Comment: @r3wt Please enlighten me. Why is writing (non-ansi standard) `||` better than writing `OR`, and how does it relate to the OP's question?

Comment: @robbycornelissen I don't get r3wt's point either. Seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: I've had 1 to many tonight i'm afraid. sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the SQL `IN` operator to test if a column is in a list of values. Here's how to write it with MySQLI:

```
$in_str = implode(', ', array_map(function($title) use ($con) {
    return "'" . $con->real_escape_string($title) . "'";
}, $_POST['check_list']));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE first_title IN ($in_str) OR second_title IN ($in_str)";

$result = $con->query($sql);
```

Comment: To whoever suggested an edit: the `WHERE` clause tests whether any of the conditions is true of the row, the `IN` operator tests whether a specific column's value is in the list.

Comment: how about with mysql instead of mysqli?

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `$con->real_escape_string`, and use `mysql_query` instead of `$con->query`.

Comment: the logic is the same, you just need to use the appropriate syntax for the API.

Comment: my ide says there is syntax error in that 3rd line: }), $_POST['check_list']));

Comment: Fixed it, I had an extra parenthesis

Comment: i'm actually adding this "OR" to a statement already in place.  how do i add it?  it currently says "where (something and something)"... so i'm thinking to add it like this: "where (something and something) and (first_title IN ($in_str) OR second_title IN ($in_str))"... does that look right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58532/discussion-between-leoarce-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

try this dynamic where condition in your code

```
   <?php
    $arr_where = array();

    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) { 
        $arr_where[] = " first_name='$check' OR last_name='$check' ";
    }

    $where_text = implode("OR", $arr_where);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE ".$where_text;
    ?>
```